# Unable to use GoogleMapsComponent in a Standalone Angular 16 app

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular-material, angular16, angular-standalone-components

#### Description

I'm unable to use Google Maps Component with a Angular 16 app which doesn't use NgModules.
I have imported GoogleMapModule in the imports array of my standalone component and yet the template cannot recognize the <google-map> component.

TS Code Snippet of component:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { GoogleMapsModule } from "@angular/google-maps";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  template: "<div>Hello {{ title }}</div><google-maps />",
  standalone: true,
  imports: [GoogleMapsModule],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = "Angular CLI Template";
}
```

#### Environment

- Angular: 16.0.1
- google-maps: 16.0.4
- Browser(s): Chrome
- Operating System (e.g. Windows, macOS, Ubuntu): macOS

#### Reproduction

Code Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/angular-cli-n61gs
Steps to reproduce:

1. Add @angular/google-maps@16.04 as a dependency
2. Add GoogleMapsModule to the imports array in App Component
3. Mark App Component as standalone.
4. Use <google-map /> anywhere in App Component's template.

#### Expected Behavior

App should run fine and render in the browser.

#### Actual Behavior

App fails to Compile stating <google-maps /> is not a known element.

[image]

Comment: are you sure `<google-maps>` doesn't need a closing tag? like `</google-maps>`

Comment: @Andres2142 closing the tag the way he did is now supported for angular component tags in this version of Angular

Comment: I created a standalone Angular application, installed @angular/google-maps, imported it into app.component, and was able to use the <google-map /> tag just fine.  Can you update your question with what your main.ts file looks like?

Also, your codesandbox link takes you to an angular 15 app that is not set to standalone, making the reproduction steps hard to follow.

But this seems to be working fine for me.  Maybe try restarting your dev server if you haven't already?

Comment: In your reproduction steps, when you marked the app.component as standalone, did you get rid of the app.module?  If you are working with a standalone angular application, you should be bootstrapping your application by passing in the AppComponent and the appConfig object: `bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig).catch((err) => console.error(err));`